# Как изменить цвет скролла?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Как изменить цвет вертикаьного скролла в `QScrollBar`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [стилями Qt (stylesheet)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html), например:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListWidget

app = QApplication([])

w = QListWidget()
w.addItems([f'item #{i}' for i in range(100)])
w.setStyleSheet("""
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: 2px solid grey;
    background: #32CC99;
}
""")
w.show()

app.exec()
```

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Если захочется применить стиль на все виджеты, то метод `setStyleSheet` вызываете у объекта `QApplication`.

Comment: @fangry, лучше создайте отдельный вопрос, ваш коммент уже не по теме, да и код в нем не посмотреть нормально ;)

Comment: Создал [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658322/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-qmessagebox-%d0%b2-pyqt5-python]

Comment: Не могу понять почему не применяется стиль, всё сделал как Вы написали, но ничего не изменилось [screen](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/04/25/0023/0248/1507576/76/127b3d74b0.jpg)

Comment: @fangry, а мой код работает у вас?

Comment: Да, всё работает как у вас на скрине

Comment: @fangry, ну не знаю... пробовали заполнить ваш список, чтобы вертикальный ползунок появился? :D

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57687/discussion-between-fangry-and-gil9red).