# Работа с QMessageBox: как изменить название стандартных кнопок и как в `setInformativeText` добавить картинку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, gui

Как изменить название стандартных кнопок?

Как в `setInformativeText` добавить картинку?

Код:

```
msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setWindowTitle("Информация")
msg.setText("Privet")
msg.setInformativeText("dfgdfgdg")
msg.setDetailedText("dgdfg23")
result = msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
retval = msg.exec_()
if retval == QMessageBox.Ok:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый просто вариант:

```
msg = QMessageBox()
msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
# msg.setIconPixmap(pixmap)  # Своя картинка

msg.setWindowTitle("Информация")
msg.setText("Privet")
msg.setInformativeText("InformativeText")
msg.setDetailedText("DetailedText")

okButton = msg.addButton('Окей', QMessageBox.AcceptRole)
msg.addButton('Отмена', QMessageBox.RejectRole)

msg.exec()
if msg.clickedButton() == okButton:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Сложный вариант это найти файлы перевода Qt (вроде бы расширение у них `.qm`), познакомиться с классом [QTranslator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html) и подгружать файл перевода, тогда стандартные названия будут заменены

Comment: А возможно ли вместо текста в `msg.setInformativeText("InformativeText")` поставить картинку??

Comment: @fangry, ага, грязным хаком, подменив виджет, поэтому лучше возьмите QDialog и накидайте на него нужные вам виджеты -- разницы не заметите